# emacs' internal documentation missing info?

Tags: documentation

Emacs 26.1 on Debian 10 stable

---

I have previously used the Windows version of Emacs and now I'm back in Linux (thanks to it).

When pressing `C-h i d` there seemed to be a lot of more information in the Windows version.

Now I can only see Org-mode, and Emacs FAQ among other things I don't really need right now. The Window Version had the (full) Emacs documentation, Lisp documentation and a lot more.

Am I missing something? Or Looking in the wrong place?

[image]

Comment: The set of manuals available typically depends on your platform and Emacs build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consult your Linux distribution packages. eg in Debian many of the docs are bundled separately because of FSF policies.

See [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/emacs-common-non-dfsg) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a more intuitive package name, "non-dsfg" was not one of them.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of crazy and non-indusive for beginners too.